# Google Authentification Laravel Socialite gives 403 Error when asking for 'profile' scope

Tags: laravel, google-authentication, laravel-socialite

As the title says, I'm getting a 403 Forbidden Error when asking for the 'profile' scope.

Here's my code

```
// routes/web.php

Route::get('google', 'Auth\GoogleAuth@auth')->name('google-signup');
Route::get('googlecallback', 'Auth\GoogleAuth@callback');
```

```
// Auth/GoogleAuth.php methods

public function auth()
    {
        return Socialite::driver('facebook')->redirect();
    }

    public function callback()
    {
        $socialUser = Socialite::driver('facebook')->user();
        dd($socialUser);
    }
```

The reason I know it's the 'profile' scope is because when I tried

```
public function auth()
    {
        return Socialite::driver('facebook')->setScopes(['email','openid'])->redirect();
    }
```

Everything worked, prefectly, I get the email and the id, only I don't get user info without the 'profile' scope. and I need said information (name, first name, last name ..etc).

I tried the stateless() solution but I kept getting the same 403 Error.
I saw some similar questions here and in github but the solutions didn't work for me either.

Laravel version 7.x
Laravel Socialite version 4.4

I'd appreciate any help.

Answer (score 4):

Okay... This question is out there a lot with few (or wrong) answers. I happened to run into this on 2 different Amazon Lightspeed instances with the exact same code installed and on one server Google login/callback worked fine and on the other 403.

This is MOD SECURITY issue. It's blocking the use of .profile which is in the Laravel code apparently or perhaps required to pull down the Google user data. What you need to be able to do to fix this is turn off the ID for this rule in mod-sec. For me that was 210580.

> Message: Access denied with code 403 (phase 2). Matched phrase
> ".profile" at ARGS:scope. [file
> "/etc/apache2/modsecurity.d/rules/comodo_free/08_Global_Other.conf"]
> [line "57"] [id "210580"] [rev "2"] [msg "COMODO WAF: OS File Access
> Attempt||aeroscale.net|F|2"] [data "Matched Data: .profile found
> within ARGS:scope: email profile openid
> https:/www.googleapis.com/auth/userinfo.profile
> https:/www.googleapis.com/auth/userinfo.email"] [severity "CRITICAL"]
> [tag "CWAF"] [tag "Other"] Apache-Error: [file "apache2_util.c"] [line
> 273] [level 3] [client 73.238.35.209] ModSecurity: Access denied with
> code 403 (phase 2). Matched phrase ".profile" at ARGS:scope. [file
> "/etc/apache2/modsecurity.d/rules/comodo_free/08_Global_Other.conf"]

I added that to my Plesk exception list in Mod Security and it started working on this server. Ironically I don't have that rule installed on the other server and it works fine. It's a slightly lower end server though so perhaps Amazon runs a different rule set on them.

Comment: Turning off the rules is really stupid way to resolve the issue. the better way to do is add new customer rules that ignores specific rules id for specific url.